# Changing the menu character into a x

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a responsive menu following some tutorial on the internet

```
 <a class="menu_button"  href="#"><span class="icon">≡</span> </a>
    <div id='menu'>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="link">LINK1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">lINK2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">LINK3</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">LINK4</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">LINK5</a></li>
                <li><a id="selected" href="link">LINK6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

The menù it's shown when the user press the link and it uses this script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_button').click(function(e) {
    //    $("#menu").toggleClass("show");
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I want to do that when the menù it's closed there is **≡** symbol but when I open it I want to turn it into a **x**.

How can I do this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu_button').click(function(e) {
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
        if ($("#menu").is(":visible"))
            $(this).find(".icon").text("&times;");
        else
            $(this).find(".icon").text("≡");
    });
});
```

Comment: thank u man! It works :) Wait 10 minutes and I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu_button').click(function(e) {
    $("#menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.icon').html("x");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps, maybe it's not a complete solution, maybe is not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: No it doesn't work! Check correctly and tell what does it say.

Comment: If you talk about the callback in slideToggle, you are true, but I don't update my answer because there are so many answers yet. When I publish this solution there aren't another answers

Comment: Okay buddy... Agreed! `:P`

Comment: I'm spanish, and it's very extended the think that we are hard learning new languages, so I'm proud to talk and write in english and people understands me.

Answer (score 1):

You can amend the `text()` of the `.icon` within the click handler. Try this:

```
$('.menu_button').click(function(e) {        
    $("#menu").stop(true).slideToggle(function() {
        $(this).find('.icon').text(function(i, val) {
            return val === 'x' ? '≡' : 'x';
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should set logic once animation is done, i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff good point, updated. Added `stop()` too to prevent multiple clicks queueing up animations.

Answer (score 1):

This is another way, toggling a class to use CSS `transition`:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu_button').click(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $("#menu").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
a.menu_button {
    display: inline-block;
}
#menu {
    display: none;
}
.icon {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.menu_button.open {
    height: 30px;
}
.menu_button.open .icon span:nth-child(1), .menu_button.open .icon span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(0px, 13px) rotate(-45deg) scalex(1.3);
    margin: 0;
}
.menu_button.open .icon span:nth-child(2) {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.menu_button.open .icon span:nth-child(3) {
    transform: translate(0px, 9px) rotate(45deg) scalex(1.3);
}
.icon span {
    background: #1d1d1b;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="menu_button"  href="#"><span class="icon"><span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span></span> </a>
    <div id='menu'>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="link">LINK1</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">lINK2</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">LINK3</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">LINK4</a></li>
                <li><a href="link">LINK5</a></li>
                <li><a id="selected" href="link">LINK6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

***src:*** https://stackoverflow.com/a/25845803/1414562